# The correct order to rebuild the WSO2 repositories on my local computer

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I want to rebuild the WSO2 EI from source code on Git repository. But I do not know how to start this job. I have already sent an email to dev@wso2.org to get advice for along time. But I have not received any information from them yet.

I also downloaded and rebuilt the carbon-commons repository tag that was used for the WSO2 AS 5.3.0 release successfully. But I do not know what is the  tag of WSO2 EI from the carbon repository?
(following this reference link: https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon4411/Working+with+the+Source+Code)

Could you give me some advice to do this job quickly ?

Comment: Here is a blogpost describing how to do this, maybe it will help:

https://www.yenlo.com/blog/building-wso2-products-from-source

Comment: Yes, thank you for your reference. I also read this blogpost but it was built on the old version. I am trying to build the WSO2 EI on the Git repository, but it does not success. Error same as the comment under the blogpost.

Comment: You should be able to build the master branch without building any other downstream repositories. If you find any errors in building it, please post it .

Comment: Or If you want to build any released version, checkout to the release tag and build it.

Comment: I was building the master branch and got the error:  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
12.4:test (default-test) on project org.wso2.carbon.ei.tests.transport: Executio
n default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:tes
t failed: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or
System.exit called ?

Comment: Try to build project with "mvn clean install -U -Dmaven.test.skip=true" command

Comment: I already tried with "mvn clean install -U -Dmaven.test.skip=true" command. But there is same problem.  [] FATAL - TomcatBundleActivator Error while starting
server org/apache/xerces/util/SecurityManager
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/util/SecurityManager
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.ServerManager.getSecuredDocumentBuild
er(ServerManager.java:269)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.ServerManager.inputStreamToDOM(Server
Manager.java:225)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.ServerManager.init(ServerManager.java
:108)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build the EI pack by cloning [product-ei](https://github.com/wso2/product-ei.git) repository from the Github and checkout to the relevant tag. All WSO2 related dependencies are hosted in WSO2 nexus repository. Therefore you don't need to build dependent repositories. You can build EI project without running test cases by simply running "mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true".

If you need to do a code change for dependent repository, then you can do the necessary changes in relevant dependent repository and build the repositories in following order.
[image]

For example, If you need to do a code change to the Synapse, first you need to build the Synapse. Then build Carbon-mediation project with updated Synapse version. Finally build EI with latest synapse and carbon-mediation version.

Comment: I built the EI package successfully, but when I run the integrator.bat in the wso2ei-6.6.0-SNAPSHOT.zip, I got the error: FATAL - TomcatBundleActivator Error while starting server org/apache/xerces/util/SecurityManager java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/util/SecurityManager at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.ServerManager.getSecuredDocumentBuild er(ServerManager.java:269) at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.ServerManager.inputStreamToDOM(Server Manager.java:225) at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.ServerManager.init(ServerManager.java :108)

Comment: Seems it can't identify xerces library and you are running integrator on Windows OS. Since master branch is current development branch, there might be ongoing development. Could you please build the product in different tag such as v6.5.0 and try it?

Comment: Yes, I built the product as v6.5.0 successfully. Thank you for your help!